# Eclipse / Spring Tools Suite blank space above split windows

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, workspace, blank-line, sts

How to make this blank space above my code modules disappear?

[image]

I have tried everything but nothing seems to remove this blank space above my code. Just wondering if there is a way to fix this. Thanks

Comment: This is the title bar of the editor area when you display multiple editors side by side in the editor area. It will not be shown if you drag the editors a little further out so that they are in their own view stacks.